# Firebase: repeate the username in posts collection or should I use the ID?

Tags: firebase

I'm new using firebase and nosql.

I have a collection USERS, with many users. The users collection is like this:

```
users
  |
  ---- -MOFidfjdUSJFDJ (the user unique ID)
          |
          ----- username: josh (username)
          |
          ----- email: j@j.com
          |
          ----- name: josh ss s
```

And each user can create posts:

```
Posts
  |
  ---- -Mjfhdidfdufduf (the post id)
           |
           ------ username: (SHOULD I USE JOSH OR THE USER KEY -MOFidfjdUSJFDJ?)
           |
           ------ postText: text user enter
           |
           ------ profileIMG: (repeate the profile collection img or use the key?)
```

So in posts I should have `username`, a `text` user posted and his `profile image` (from a collection).

The problem is, User can change his `username` if he wants and can change his `profile picture`. If I use id I only update the username in users. But if I repeate username in each post and user has about 1000 posts, I should update his username in all this posts.

My question is: Should I use the IDs from the other collection or repeate the user and profileIMG in each post?

If I should repeate user, for example, `josh` and profileIMG `/images/josh.jpg` how can I update all at once using a firebase?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `Posts`, use the following:

```
Posts
  |
  ---- -Mjfhdidfdufduf (the post id)
           |
           ------ userId: userID_value
           |
           ------ postText: text user enter
```

use the `userID` as a value of the `userId`. This way when you write a post and you want to retrieve user info, you can just read the document related to that user under `users` collection.

If you update the `username` and the `profileImg`, then you need to only update in one place thus doing one read.

---

So basically:

1. if the user has 1000 posts
2. user updated his profile image and username
3. You will update only the user document inside the user collection
4. If you enter a page that will contain a list of posts for that user, it will retrieve the newly username and profile image.

---

Now if in your application, you have a list of posts of all users, then it will be easier to have `username`, `profileImg` and `postText` under each document inside collection `Posts`. Then you have to update all posts of the user, but you need to take into account that users  aren't going to be updating the profile image or username daily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will show posts in a Feed, so I can have posts from many users there. In this case after user change his profile picture should I execute a firebase function? or can I upload in a simple command in my reactjs app like: `firebase.database().ref().update(updates)`? thanks again!